# List of abbreviations using Acro + Hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, acronyms, acro

I want to get a list of abbreviations where the acronyms have a hyperlink to the list. As far as I understood, the acro package should work with hyperref and do what I want. Unfortunately, my example is not working as I expected. Can anyone tell me how to get a list of abbreviations with working hyperlinks (at best, using the acro package)?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareAcronym{cd}{
short = CD ,
long = compact disc
}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\ac{cd}
\newpage
\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add the make-links option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to link the acronym to its entry in the list of acronyms, the `acro` package offers to `make-list` boolean when used in combination with the `hyperref` package. Initially, it is set fo false which is why you don't get the hyperlinks in your document.

[image]

Thus, adding

```
\acsetup{make-links}
```

to your preamble will result in the expected hyperlinks.